# Formatting output in JOptionPane (java.io.printStream@46ee7fe8)

Tags: java, swing, joptionpane

What I've written is basically a small application to compute something, but with a very simple GUI attached. It takes a few parameters using the `JOptionPane` dialog boxes, and then uses another box to display the result.

The problem is, I need to use `printf` in the result message to round the result to get, for example, 0.48 instead of 0.484848484848. The way I've always been doing it in applications like this is something like `System.out.printf("%.2f", [name of the variable])`. It works just fine in the console, but with `JOptionPane` it views exactly what's in the title, and sends me to the console, where the correct and formatted result is displayed. I'd like for it to be displayed in the window. What should I do?

Comment: System.out methods will always write to the console. To write something to the UI you'll need somehing like setting the text in a JLabel.

Comment: Improved formatting

Comment: @niqueco - yes, i should have thought more about what's System.out.printf and what's it's actual function. But i've used String.format like ub3rst4r suggested and everything works fine. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `String.format()` and not `System.io.printf()`

Example:

```
float number = 0.48484848;
String formatted = String.format("%.2f", number);
JDialog dialog = pane.createDialog(parentComponent, formatted);
```